# text cleared when clicked again the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in coding a inline editable field. everything seems to work fine but when I click again in the input field, the existing text disappears. I cannot figure out what is problem.

```
var name;

$('span#editable').click(function(){
    name=$(this).text();
    $(this).html('');
    $('<input>')
        .attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'fname',
            'id': 'inlineEditableText',
            'size': '30',
            'value': name
        })
        .appendTo('#editable');
    $('#inlineEditableText').focus();
});

var delayTimer = ''; // this is used when browsers like Chrome and Safari call the blur event twice
$(document).on('blur','#inlineEditableText', function() {
    //alert("blur");
    if (delayTimer == '') delayTimer = setTimeout(calledAfterDelay, 50);
});

function calledAfterDelay() {
    if($("#inlineEditableText").val() != ""){
        $.ajax({
            url: Config.baseUrl + 'some.php',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "id" :<?= $selectedSpace->getId(); ?> ,
                "name" :$("#inlineEditableText").val()
            }),
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                Sapphire.Utilities.flashSuccess("Space renamed!");
            }
        });
    } else {
        Sapphire.Utilities.flashError('Please enter name'); 
    }   
    $('#editable').text(name);
    delayTimer = ''; // reset the timer so that the method can be run again
}

$(document).on('keyup','#inlineEditableText', function(e){  
    name = $(this).val();
    if(e.keyCode==13 || e.keyCode==27){
        $('#inlineEditableText').blur();
        name = $(this).val();
    }
});`
```

Comment: Euh, I think you might be overwriting the input element again every time you click on it. You should check to see if you have an input with valid text already, before inserting a new input element.

Comment: @Shilly - you are correct here...but even he is creating new element problem is not assigning correct text to created element...applying text on span return nothing if there is no text in span ..that might be reason of blank

Comment: Indeed, your solution will work perfectly, assuming he wants to recreate the input element every time. I'm just wondering now why the input isn't part of the initial html.

Comment: Yes, #Shilly, you are right.

Comment: I need it should not clear the text when clicked again.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with this line of code

```
  name=$(this).text();//this will return you text of span element not of input element 
    $(this).html('');//this clears your span element
```

So if you want to preseve text of the input element you need to take text of input element like this

```
name = $('span#editable>input[type="text"]').val();
```

than assign this text value to input element you are cereating at last

so final code will be

```
$('span#editable').click(function(){
    name = $('span#editable>input[type="text"]').val();
    $(this).html('');
    $('<input>')
        .attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'fname',
            'id': 'inlineEditableText',
            'size': '30',
            'value': name
        })
        .appendTo('#editable');
    $('#inlineEditableText').focus();
});
```

### UPDATE

```
var name;
    $('#editable').click(function(){
        name=$(this).text();
        if(($('span#editable > input[type=text]')).length>0)
        {
            name = $('span#editable>input[type=text]').val();
        }

        $(this).html('');
        $('<input>')
            .attr({
                'type': 'text',
                'name': 'fname',
                'id': 'inlineEditableText',
                'size': '30',
                'value': name
            })
            .appendTo('#editable');
        $('#inlineEditableText').focus();
    });

var delayTimer = ''; 
    $(document).on('blur','#inlineEditableText', function() {
        if (delayTimer == '') delayTimer = setTimeout(calledAfterDelay, 50);
    });

    function calledAfterDelay() {
        alert("calledafterdelay");
    }

    $(document).on('keyup','#inlineEditableText', function(e){  
        name = $(this).val();
        if(e.keyCode==13 || e.keyCode==27){
            $('#inlineEditableText').blur();
            name = $(this).val();
        }
    });
```

**Full Working and Updated code : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3m1gdv7/1/)**

Comment: @MianHaseeb - check update and dont forget to upvote/accept if it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all #gurus for answers.
I have solved it. 
I have just placed a check if the input field already exist then do not append it.

```
var name;
$('span#editable').click(function(){
    if ($('span#editable').find('#inlineEditableText').length == 0)//this check does the job
    {
    name=$(this).text();
    $(this).html('');
    $('<input>')
        .attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'fname',
            'id': 'inlineEditableText',
            'size': '30',
            'value': name
        })
        .appendTo('#editable');
    $('#inlineEditableText').focus();
}
});
```

Comment: please accept answer as it helps to resolve the issue...dont forget it